# wamp server login error

Tags: wampserver

[image: the wamp appear on the desktop like this]Wamp Server problem

I have a strange problem here: when I checked the wamp mysql in the windows services it was running and the apache was stopped and after I changed the port from 80 to 8080 the wamp server icon now is green but the phpmyadmin is not working and the error msg is:

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: Are you going to http://localhost/phpmyadmin or to http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin?

Comment: It is going to localhost/phpmyadmin I want it just work normally And I searched others posts and I found others changing the port to 8080

Comment: localhost:8080/phpmyadmin works but I just want to know why and why the normal local host is not working

Comment: I think you need a port forwarding service to accomplish this. You probably don't want to get into that for a development server, and you probably don't want WAMP for a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution would be to find out why you cannot run Apache listening on port 80 and fix that.

Using the Wampmanager icon ( that the Green W icon in the system tray ) do:

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Test Port 80
```

This will load a command window and tell you what is using port 80.

Its then just a case of re-configuring whatever that is.

The normal things that get in the way are

SKYPE, TEAM VIEWER, IIS
If its IIS these can also be running and will also report as IIS, and should also be disabled from the services panel.

1. IIS
2. Web Deploy 2.0
3. MS Sql Server Reporting service.

Skype and Team Viewer can be easily re-configured not to use port 80.
IIS can be disabled from your Service panel, or even uninstalled if you never exect to use it.

**How to Configure SKYPE so it does not require port 80 or 443**

Run SKYPE
then using the menus do this:

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection

Un-Check the checkbox next to 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections'

Now restart SKYPE for these changes to take effect.

If you are running Windows 8 SKYPE comes as an app and this cannot ( as yet ) be configured in this way.
However if you uninstall the SKYPE app and install SKYPE in the old way, you can reconfigure it, and it works just as well.

**How to Configure Team Viewer so it does not require port 80 or 443**
Run TV
Extras -> Options -> Advanced -> Press the Advanced Button -> Advanced Network Connections
Check the checkbox saying [ Dont use incomming port 80 (recommended for web servers only )